# Can the two paritiy bits in the LIN-Datatelegram guarantee that every error is caught in the Identifier Field?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, parity

The LIN-TElegram has a protected Identifier Fild with a Frame-ID consisting of 6 bit, followed up by 2 Bits that build the two Parity bits.

The first Parity Bit `P0` gets calculated like this:

```
Bit0 XOR Bit1 XOR Bit2 XOR Bit4
```

The second Parity Bit `P1` gets calculated like this:

```
Bit1 XOR Bit3 XOR Bit4 XOR Bit5
```

Is there an easy way to test this in Python / Matlab? 
Or a simple mathematical solution on how to know how many bit errors can be caught by this mechanism?

I do not know if this question really belongs on SO, but I could not find a more fitting stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For example for

`Bit0 XOR Bit1 XOR Bit2 XOR Bit4`

`Bit1 XOR Bit3 XOR Bit4 XOR Bit5`

it is clear that swapping the values of bits 1 and 4 will yield the same results.

Generally, parity bits only guarantee that exactly one bit error in the inputs will get caught, but if there are more, all bets are off.